# How to get data from multiple tinputs into single toracleoutput in Talend

Tags: talend

I have 2 input sources :

1. Input is :- tOracleInput_1
2. Input is :- tOracleInput_2

Now I want to use tMap for data process and then load these 2 inputs into a single tOracleOutput.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The main question is what you mean by "data process".

a) If you just got two similar pipelines I'd create 2 Talend jobs for every data flow.

b) If you want to join the data in the tMap, you can simply use the lookup function of the tMap to join the data and then connect a `tOracleOutput`.

Answer (score 0):

Use tUnite component to connect both tOracleInput_1 and tOracleInput_2 than connect tUnite to tMap with main flow and from tMap connect a single tOracleOutput with main.

Hope this help